# Why I am getting Requested unknown parameter error?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am filling and using server side code for Jquery data table. I am using server side processing because data can be more than 10,000 but I am getting an error.

**DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'UserName' for row 0, column 0.**

Code:

```
function show()
{                
    $('#example').DataTable
    (
        {
            //data: data,
            columns: 
            [                    
                {'data': 'UserName'},
                {'data': 'Password'},
            ],
            bServerSide: true,
            sAjaxSource: 'http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx/getUsers',
            sServerMethod: 'post'
        });              
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

I have just put the relevant code above.

c# webmethod:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public void getUsers(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch)
{
    try
    {
        basicoperation bop = new basicoperation();
        DataTable dt;

        dt = bop.getUsers(iDisplayLength, iDisplayStart, iSortCol_0, sSortDir_0, sSearch); // fetching users

        dt.TableName = "usersDT";  // a datatable must be named before serialization

        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0]; 

        string jsonDataTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt); //a  data table must be serialized before transmitting

        var retObj = new
        {
            iTotalRecords = dr["TotalCount"].ToString(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords= dt.Rows.Count,
            aaData = jsonDataTable
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(retObj)); // converting a .net object to JSON

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }    

}
```

returns:

**{"iTotalRecords":"19","iTotalDisplayRecords":5,"aaData":"[{\"RowNum\":2,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":39,\"UserName\":\"adsbkj\",\"Password\":\"23123\"},{\"RowNum\":3,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":40,\"UserName\":\"adsbkj\",\"Password\":\"23123\"},{\"RowNum\":4,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":37,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"23\"},{\"RowNum\":5,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":2,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asdasd\"},{\"RowNum\":6,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":5,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asda\"}]"}**

Comment: Not sure but just add `{'data': 'Id'}` before `{'data': 'UserName'}`

Comment: I did, no effect.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) at the Returned Parameters - you're not returning the `draw` parameter. Also you can use the v1.10 syntax detailed on that page (assuming you're using that version)

Comment: You need to add another parameter to the method declaration `string sEcho`. then include it in your returned `retObj`

Comment: Can you try replacing `'data': 'UserName'` with `'data': 3` and `{'data': 'Password'}` with `{'data': 4}` to see what happens

Comment: I can only think that there's something wrong with the json data - it's valid json(I think) but it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @markpsmith it's fine i guess

Comment: @markpsmith any solution ?